# Pandas Pivot table get max with column name

Tags: pandas, database, pivot, pivot-table, data-science

I have the following pivot table

[image]

I want to get the max value from each row, but also, I need to get the column it came from.
So far I know who to get the max row of every column using this:

```
dff['State'] = stateRace.max(axis=1)
dff
```

I get this:
[image]

which is returning the correct max value but not the column it came from.

Answer (score 0):

You suffer a disadvantage getting help because you have supplied images and the question is not clear. Happy to help if the below answer doesn't help.

```
stateRace=stateRace.assign(max_value=stateRace.select_dtypes(exclude='object').max(axis=1),\
max_column=stateRace.select_dtypes(exclude='object').idxmax(axis=1))
```